# Creating undefined method behavior in Java?

Tags: java

I have got a task about a board game to suggest the best move via a method when we get an in-progress game state. I have to do it in Java.

There is a strange instruction in the task: if we get a state which can't occur in normal play then "the behavior of this method is undefined". (You can imagine this state like in chess you get a board with two kings on adjacent fields, which can't be happened in a real chess game.)

The question is: what can this instruction mean? Is there anybody who has already faced with a same problem?

First, I thought that in such a state I should throw, for example, an `IllegalStateException`. But according to another instruction line I have to throw `IllegalStateException` when I get a board with a state representing that one of the players has already won the game, or it is draw.

I have already searched for the definition of undefined behavior, but I don't know how can I use it in this case. At all, can I create this kind of behavior in Java which can be connected to this kind of case?

Comment: It means it can do anything. So yes, throwing an `IllegalStateException` should be fine. Btw, it's Java, not JAVA.

Comment: The instruction is incorrect. One player winning is a valid state. IllegalStateException is for situations where the state is invalid.

Comment: If a method has undefined behaviour you can throw "UnsupportedOperationException" assuming it should never be called.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for the comment and the correction.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The task is to suggest the best move in a given state. I think they ask IllegalStateException when one of the players has already won, because in this state I can't suggest any (best) move. The same when I get a board with an illegal state. Anyway, thanks for your answer. I will think of UnsupportedOperationException too, but I sympathize with IllegalStateException more, yet. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when the problem states "this behavior is undefined" it's just saying that they aren't going to test that condition because you can't reasonably be expected to do anything. It's not actually a task for you to complete - it's just telling you not to worry about those scenarios.

Comment: I hope you are right. :-) Maybe, I have just complicated a simple case. I thought that I should create some kind of behavior in Java which depends on the compiler or on the JVM or create some other weird behavior (as it is written in the definition of "undefined behavior"). I've just wanted to see what other people say about this (who may have more experience in Java programming/development than me). Thanks for the answer. +1

Comment: In support of the answer above: the phrase "undefined behavior" is frequently used in JavaSE javadocs (see for example [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.function.Supplier-int-boolean-) comment) to indicate, that a method is not meant to be used in some circumstances, and no guarantees regarding it's behavior can be made in those circumstances. So, in other words, you can handle such cases as you wish. :)

Comment: I have also checked the unit tests and found that these kind of illegal states are not tested anywhere. So, nobody is curious about them. I mark this answer as solution. It seems I have overcomplicated this "undefined behavior" case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write an "ImpossibleStateException" and throw this if the said case is true? 
It's part of Java's design that you can write own exception classes, so why not write one and throw it when an undefined state is happening.

I'm not sure how the said state is ever produced, I could imagine if you talk about a kind of board game, maybe somebody fiddles around with the ram or the vm and tries to cheat / hack the game.

Also, if somebody would make a deep test of EVERY possible state of the program, like every variable with every possible value the game allows, there would be around 98% cases that made no sense at all.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can write my own exception class. I've just thought that I should write some weird code which behavior depends on the implementation of the JVM or anything like this...and I've wondered how should I write it in this game case...and what others says who may have more experience in Java development. But I think now I have just complicated a simple "do-not-bother-with-this" case. But thanks for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle doc IllegalStateException:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

So I think in your sitiation it is not good solution.

Comment: Maybe, but the task is to give the best move in the given game state. Therefore I think if the game is over or the state to examine is illegal it means that I want to invoke my method at an "inappropriate time" (as doc says), because I can't suggest any (best) move. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Colossus If someone already won, there is no move left. Invoking a method before something else was done can be defined as inappropriate timing, but not this case. Instead of throwing an exception when there is no best move, just say that the game is over and no move is left.

Comment: @MeikVtune: According to the task I have to throw IllegalStateException when the game state shows that the game is over, no choice. My question is mainly related to the undefined behavior when I get an illegal game board state to examine. Anyway, inappropriate timing can occur BEFORE and/or AFTER something was done. For example, if the game is over it is inappropriate to ask what is the next (best) move. Because it doesn't make sense. As when the state is illegal. But I will think about any other solution,too. Thanks for the answer.